# How convert unsigned char to jbyteArray

Tags: java, java-native-interface

How do I convert a unsigned char buffer to a jbyteArray? I need get a C++ buffer and returns to Java through JNI.

This is my current code to do that.

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_com_rmsdk_wrapper_RMServices_getImageBuffer(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiso,
    jint w, jint h) {
    emh::PNGSurface * surface = services->getImageBuffer(w,h);
jbyteArray * buffer = (jbyteArray*)malloc(sizeof(jbyteArray)*surface->getBufferSize());
    unsigned char * imgBuff = surface->getBuffer();

    for(int i = 0; i < surface->getBufferSize();i++){
        buffer = imgBuff;
        buffer++;
        imgBuff++;
    }
    return *buffer;
};
```

I got the following error when compiling.

```
Compile++ thumb  : rmsdk <= RMSDK_Wrapper_JNI.cpp
/home/marcos/dev/workspace/rmsdk.native.wraper/jni/RMSDK_Wrapper_JNI.cpp: In function '_jbyteArray* Java_com_rmsdk_wrapper_RMServices_getImageBuffer(JNIEnv*, _jobject*, jint, jint)':
/home/marcos/dev/workspace/rmsdk.native.wraper/jni/RMSDK_Wrapper_JNI.cpp:37: error: cannot convert 'unsigned char*' to '_jbyteArray**' in assignment
make: *** [/home/marcos/dev/workspace/rmsdk.native.wraper/obj/local/armeabi/objs/rmsdk/RMSDK_Wrapper_JNI.o] Error 1
```

Ty.

Comment: jbyteArray must be created by the JVM, you cannot return an ordinary C memory location. This will crash the JVM. You should also use the helper methods for setting the values of the byte array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [these JNI array operations](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#array_operations), particularly:

- NewByteArray
- GetArrayElements
- ReleaseArrayElements

If you know a maximum size for the array beforehand, you can avoid the NewByteArray call.

If you call this infrequently, you might find it easier to use JNA.

Comment: I solved it by creating a NewByteArray, copying the content from the unsigned char buffer to a jbyte buffer and using the SetArrayByteRegion to the array. This solves my problem. This is for Android, I don't think I can use JNA.